# Comment lexer rule

Tags: comments, antlr3, lexical-analysis

I'm new to ANTLR and I've come up with this lexer rule to parse out comments, will it work?

```
COMMENT_LINE        :   (COMMENT (. - LINE_ENDING)* LINE_ENDING){$channel=hidden};
```

(I couldn't find anything regarding syntax such as this in the docs)

Comment: Besides the fact that it depends on all other lexer rules in your grammar, the minus sign, `-`, will probably cause some sort of error. Can you explain what you mean by it? And can you give a couple of examples of the strings you're trying to parse?

Comment: All the other "rules" mentioned are actually tokens, i'm trying to match the comment keyword followed by the rest of the line.

Comment: The order of lexer rules are also important. For example, if the lexer rule `ANY_CHAR : . ;` is not the last rule, the grammar will not work since any rule after that will never be able match anything since `ANY_CHAR` will gobble up everything. But I guess Bojan has successfully answered your question, right?

Comment: My previous remark *"Besides the fact that it depends on all other lexer rules in your grammar, ..."* is a bit misleading (or even incorrect!). I meant: *"Besides the fact that it may depend on some other lexer rules in your grammar, "*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rule doesn't compile at all. If you use ANTLRWorks to create a new lexer grammar, you can check a box to have it generate a lexer rule that matches single line comments. It generates this:

```
COMMENT
    :   '//' ~('\n'|'\r')* '\r'? '\n' {$channel=HIDDEN;}
    ;
```

Alternatively, you can use something like this to match single line comments:

```
COMMENT_LINE 
    : COMMENT (options{greedy=false;}: .)* LINE_ENDING {$channel=HIDDEN;}
    ;
```

Comment: Cool. any reason why ANTLRWorks states that "Cannot display rule COMMENT_LINE because start state not found"?